# Sign In with Custom Token In Supabase

Tags: c#, .net, desktop, supabase

I want to Sign In with custom Token using **Supabase** just like in Firebase.
anyone provide  a solution in c# language.

I have a Custom Token , I want to Sign In without email and password , because I want to use custom token and retrieve data from supabase with the help of access token.